# Vuex: Is there a "best practice" for determining whether a state change has taken place?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

My team and I have created a Vuex module which stores the user-input contents of a form. If the form contains unsaved changes, and the user attempts to navigate away, then we would like to warn the user in order to allow them a chance to cancel navigation.

It would be nice if we could simply check against a built-in getter. Maybe something like:

```
if (this.$store.getters['myModule/hasChanged']) {
    // alert user
} else {
    // allow user to proceed
}
```

We've talked about deep-watching the state and generating a hash every time a mutation takes place, but question the performance consequences that approach could introduce.

We've considered flipping a boolean (either in the component which holds the form or in the state itself)  to signal whether changes have taken place, but agree that we'd rather not hard-code some value like that.

Is there a best practice for determining whether the state of a given module has changed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use another approach:

1. store all inputs in a component itself
2. track changes in a components itself and set some boolean flag `isChanged`
3. When a user navigates away:

```
if (this.isChanged) {
    // alert user
} else {
    // store all inputs to a state
    // allow user to proceed
}
```